# can .proto file fields be without values?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I received "missing field number" error. Is it possible to declare fields without value? since i do not have a default value to the fields.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tutorial;

message Person {
  required string name;
  required string email;
}
```

Comment: It isn't a value that is missing; it is a field number. However, "required" doesn't exist in proto3 ("optional" does, but refers to whether or not definite assignment is tracked); for example `string name = 1; string email = 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field number is not refer to a default value but each field in the message definition has a unique number. These numbers are used to identify your fields in the message binary format, and should not be changed once your message type is in use.

[More info here in the doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#simple)